# -bash: rspec: command not found

Tags: bash, path, rspec

I found rspec in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-2.6.0/lib
I even put a path to it in my .bash_profile:
PATH="/usr/local/bin:/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-2.6.0/lib:

But when I enter rspec in terminal I get command not found. Even when I'm in the same directory as the file rspec?

Besides being a noob, what am I doing wrong?

**Update:**I was able to execute rspec using "bundle exec rspec" but I'd like to figure out why I can't just use rspec.

Answer (score 0):

Check that your PATH environment variable is what you expect.  `echo $PATH` 
Check that your target binary has executable permission.  `ls -l /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rspec-2.6.0/lib` 
Check again. `which rspec`

Answer (score 0):

for a file to be executable as a binary you generally need to:

```
(a) make the file executable by running chmod 755 /path/to/scripts/awesometask.gem 
(b) add a "shebang" to the top of the file (first line) that contains the path of the interpreter for the script: #!/usr/bin/ruby 
(c) execute file with full path: /path/to/scripts/awesometask.gem 
or
(c1) add the folder where the file is to PATH: PATH=$PATH:/path/to/scripts
```