# Mac Rspec install fail: -bash: rspec: command not found

Tags: macos, rspec

I am a newbie and been stuck with this for 2 days; I am about to go crazy.
I am starting to learn Ruby and we got to Rspec.
I installed Rspec with `gem install rspec` and everything goes ok, but when I execute `which rspec` I get nothing returned.
When I execute "**gem which rspec**" I get:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-3.10.0/lib/rspec.rb
```

My $PATH is:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.profile" ]] && source "$HOME/.profile" # Load the default .profile


export PATH="/usr/local/opt/openssl/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"

alias laptop='bash <(curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/monfresh/laptop/master/laptop)'

export PATH="$HOME/.bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rspec-3.10.0/lib:$PATH"
```

And "which ruby" throws:

```
/usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby
```

I took a look at these two posts but had no luck with them [Post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30687150/bash-error-rspec-command-not-found)
,
[Post 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7504347/bash-rspec-command-not-found)

Any help will be really appreciated!